# Должен ли номер версии библиотеки соответствовать номеру buildToolsVersion?

Tags: java, android

Вот в моем проекте я только обратил внимание на то, что мой `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` вот такой... А номера версий библиотек которые я добавил

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

все отличаются... И подсвечиваются желтым, когда я навожу курсор говорит, что доступна новая версия... я все библиотеки поменял на новые и проект прекратил загружаться показывая кучу ошибок и вот от сюда у меня появилось 2 вопроса

1. Должны ли на самом деле номера версии библиотек соответствовать
       номеру buildToolsVersion?
2. Действительно ли нужно держать в своем проекте самые последние
   версии библиотек или если работает так то лучше не трогать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. нет, не должны. Единственное ограничение - версия support библиотеки должна быть не ниже версии используемого SDK. Например, если используете SDK 22, то библиотеки должны быть версии 22 или старше.
2. Желательно так и делать, но не обязательно. Я с этим не спешу обычно, т. к. часто в нововведениях присутствуют баги, которые исправляются в минорных версиях (23.0.1, 23.0.2...)

Comment: А какая версия сейчас считается самой последней и стабильной?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, каждый считает по-своему. Я использую 22.0.0 и targetSdk 22

Comment: и sdk версия тоже я так понял, должна быть в таком случае не выше чем 22